# System.out.println() vs Hibernate.initialize(proxy)

Tags: java, hibernate

How can we solve this error correctly?

```
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role:
```

I have a hard time to understand and solve this exception. In my application, I need to retrieve a list of objects which are mapped to multiple tables. I try to

```
for(SampleItem item : list) {
   // Hibernate.initialize(every item's field)
}
```

But is keep getting the above error. I can simply solve this problem by 1 like of the code:

```
System.out.println(list)
```

So I wonder which is better approach (pros and cons) to solve this exception. I personally think Hibernate.initialize() would be a better option; but not sure why (since hibernate introduce this function, probably)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you have retrieved an entity called `Movie` from database using hibernate and this entity has a collection of `Actor` entities with property `actors` then by default hibernate loads the collection of `Actor` entities lazily. It means the `Movie` entity is given a proxy object for its collection property `actors`.

Now when you try to access elements of this proxy property `actors` after closing the hibernate session then you will get `LazyInitializationException`.

To fix the issue you will have 2 options.

1. As mentioned by Utpal in his answer you can set the fetching strategy as `EAGER` for the collection property.
2. Call Hibernate.initialize() and pass the collection property to tell hibernate to initialize the collection elements. This has to be done before you close the session.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I understand that I need to call Hibernate.initialize() before closing the session and that was the approach I tried first. However, when I involved the System.out.println(), it works perfectly. And If I remember correctly, this technique has never mentioned in the hibernate doc. So I was just wonder if there is any back-side of using that approach?

Comment: I am not sure if it is mentioned in official manual but the explanation is given in official java doc here - https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/Hibernate.html#initialize(java.lang.Object)

Comment: coming to `System.out.println()` just prints the object to console, so I guess you are overriding the `toString()` methods of entities and trying to access the collection elements in the method so that may be the reason the collection is getting inialized

Answer (score 0):

```
fetch=FetchType.EAGER
```

Try this where you have mapped your POJO.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. However, I don't thing it would an optimized strategy in general.